# Why isn't cross origin policy enforced?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
       $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/" + $("#nameOfCountry").val(),
        { fullText: "true" }, function (data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
            $('#answer').html(data[0].capital);
       });
```

I get the response from the other server.
So my question is: why doesn't the browser enforce the cross origin policy here?

Comment: Because the server says so: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: It‘s called CORS, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is never enforced by the server. It is enforced by the browser.

In this case, the server has used [the CORS standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that tells the browser that it has permission to share the data with any other site.

Comment: How is it possible? I understand the SOP is all about protecting the client from evil requests. So it the "evil" server enables SOP, is it becoming OK???

Comment: "How is it possible?" — I linked to the spec.

Comment: "So it the "evil" server enables SOP" — What? No. That's the opposite of what I said. The server hosting the data (which is the potential victim in the attack) tells the browser that the data is not sensitive and that the *other* server is not evil (or at least, that it doesn't matter if the data is exposed to an evil server because the data is not sensitive).